# long press menu not working when using dialog android

Tags: android, dialog, contextmenu, menuitem, long-press

i use long press menu in my activity when dialog open.
it display well but not do anything when i click on menu options.

i want to close dialog when 'Close' menu option clicked

please give better suggestion on this ,
here is my code

```
ImageView img,image,image1,image2;
Bitmap a;
String f,s;
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 3;
String imgDecodableString;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    editor = pref.edit();


    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    Button getSignature = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getSign);


    getSignature.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            makdrtd();

        }
    });
}

protected void makdrtd() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signdialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Pen Size");


    Button make = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.makesign1);
    image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveimg);
    image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveimg1);

    registerForContextMenu(image);


            dialog.show();
}


@Override   
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
{  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");    
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Close");//groupId, itemId, order, title   
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SMS");   
}

@Override    
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
        if(item.getTitle()=="Close"){  
            image.setImageBitmap(null);  

        }    
        else if(item.getTitle()=="SMS"){  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sending sms code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }else{  
           return false;  
        }    
      return true;    
  }   

public void function1(int id){  
    Toast.makeText(this, "function 1 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}  
public void function2(int id){  
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SWork.class);
    startActivity(i);

}  






    }
```

Comment: looked like you just need to give make button an on click listener

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void makdrtd() {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signdialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Pen Size");

    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveimg);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveimg1);
    Button make = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.makesign1);
    registerForContextMenu(image);
    dialog.show();

    image1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ADB = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            ADB.setTitle("Title of second dialog");
            ADB.setMessage("Message to show user.");
            ADB.setNeutralButton("ButtonText", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog2 = ADB.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't wont to dialog dismiss when make button click. I want it when image button long press and select remove option

Comment: So you want to show a dialog on a long press and give a remove option and maybe a cancel option?

Comment: That would be 2 dialogs if you want another option on a long press

Comment: it's not work.when i long pressed on image1 it close my application

Comment: Is the application crashing or just closing?